# Charts in ASP.NET 3.5: Whats the best option?

Tags: asp.net, charts

Can anyone suggest some best options to include charting feature in my ASP.NET pages ? I am using VS 2008 . I would like to have charts like google analytics charts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsft just released the new Charting COntrols for (ASP).NET. 
YOu can download the controls here, [MS Download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en).

Be sure to check out the *What Others Are Downloading* links at the bottom they provide links to the Visual Studio integration tools.

I've worked with these controls on a few projects now and have to say, they work excellently, in both Windows Forms as ASP.NET!

Comment: Be sure to try em out. I believe they are purchased from Dundas by MS and then incorporated in the Framework.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new ASP.NET Charting control that you can use. Details in [this post from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with [Dundas Chart](http://www.dundas.com/Products/Chart/index.aspx) in the past and thought it was great.

If you are using JQuery, then you could do worse than look at [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

Answer (score 1):

[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) is a very nice client-side charting library for jQuery (which plays well with ASP.NET)

Another nice (and free) charting library for .NET is [NPlot](http://www.nplot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics uses Flash for charts and MS charts are static. For nice Flash charts with ASP.NET integration check out [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com).