# how to show graphs on sharepoint MOSS site

Tags: sharepoint, graph

I want to show graphs on sharepoint site .how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer to this question: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086469/charts-in-asp-net-3-5-whats-the-best-option/1086491#1086491), it describes the MS Carthing COntrols You need .NET 3.5 SP1 though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ChartPart](http://www.codeplex.com/ChartPart) onb Codeplex.com.

Comment: anything else option please ? i want any Microsoft specified control to do so . is that present ? please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether the origin of the chart is excel, but if you have excel services which is part of the Enterpise edition of MOSS 2007, you can upload the excel document to a library and then use one of the excel webparts to show the worksheet which contains the graph.   You will benefit from people being able to update the excel document within sharepoint and the chart being updated automatically

Answer (score 0):

try using http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/SharePoint/index.aspx - They are amazing and give great results.

You can also download a trial version!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can try VfS. Watch this video tutorial "[Create Chart in SharePoint Site in few clicks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSxAajlUnt4&feature=player_embedded)".

[Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/) offers nice easy Chart WebPart Designer for SharePoint 2007 and 2010.

[image]